# How to safely upload many GB of data to Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, upload, amazon-s3

I am backing up my personal photo/video library to *Amazon S3* (several hundred GB).

I am currently using **Cyberduck** on my Mac to drag & drop, but I've already had a few fail without a clear *retry/resume* behavior.

I'd like to find a way to upload a directory with confidence that they are all transferred completely, and with a clear way to retry/resume any that failed.

What would you recommend? A command line approach is fine.

Comment: If you're on a Mac, is there a reason you can't just mount the SSH connection as a disk and run Time Machine against that disk? (I don't use a Mac myself but I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work, and AFAIK Time Machine is incremental which saves you bandwidth)

Comment: woah, that's kind of a crazy idea. Never thought of using S3 with TM. However, I don't need TM and would rather do a one time full backup. I mentioned that I'm on a Mac, but I'm curious if there is something that would work with Linux too. For example, would `rsync` work for this? I'm not familiar with it enough to know which flags to use, but it seems like a reliable tool.

Comment: `rsync` should work and is easy to use, just google some examples. There's also `duplicity` which wraps around rsync to create a time machine-like backup solution, works well. See https://easyengine.io/tutorials/backups/duplicity-amazon-s3/

Answer (score 1):

According to your problem you can try [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/be-download.html)

Features of Bucket Explorer

- You can browse buckets and the files stored at Amazon S3.
- Upload and download files, to and from Amazon S3 buckets.
- Bucket Explorer works on every OS where Java is supported.

**Bucket Explorer** comes with Multipart upload feature.This allows you to upload a single object as a set of parts. In upload process, each part is a portion of the object's data, and each part can be uploaded independently. Multipart Upload offers many benefits over simple upload, especially when object size is very large.